# Portable way to show the contents of the current directory

Tags: common-lisp

I want to provide additional information to the user during a `restart-case` for missing input files.

Is there a portable way to print out the files in the current directory?

Comment: Uiop (included with ASDF) has portable filesystem/os utilities. `(uiop/filesystem:directory-files (uiop/os:getcwd))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at [File System Concepts](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/20_a.htm), specifically at [`directory`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_dir.htm).

E.g.,

- use `(directory "~/*")` to get the list of files in your home,
- use `(directory "~/*/")` to get the list of directories in your home,
- and `(directory "~/**/*")` to get the list of all files in all subdirectoris in your home

Note that `directory` may take implementation-specific arguments like `:full`.

If you are using [`asdf`](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) (you should!), you might want to take a look at [`uiop`](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/blob/master/uiop/README.md) which comes with it.

PS. If your implementation does not support `~` in pathname to refer to the home directory, you can use [`user-homedir-pathname`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_user_h.htm) instead.

Comment: Note that Tilde in a pathname as the Homedirectory is implementation specific, though I would expect that all Unix/Linux-based implementations will support it.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to uiop was the hint I needed. This is what I use now in my test case and which works perfectly for me:

```
 (defun file-is-missing ()
  (let* ((cwd (uiop:getcwd))
         (files (uiop:directory-files cwd)))
    (format t "~&Current directory: ~a~%" cwd)
    (dolist (file files)
      (format t "~&~3T~a" file))
    (format t "~&Provide new file: ")
    (list (read-line))))

(defun read-file (file)
  (restart-case
      (with-open-file (s file :direction :input :if-does-not-exist :error)
        (do ((l (read-line s) (read-line s nil 'eof)))
            ((eq l 'eof) "Reached end of file.")
          (format t "~&*** ~A~%" l)))
    (New-File (filename)
      :interactive file-is-missing
      (read-file filename))))
```

Comment: You should use `*QUERY-IO*` when prompting for a new file (in the `READ-LINE` and the `FORMAT` before it). That way development environments (such as SLIME/SLY) can understand that it's a prompt. You should also put a `(FINISH-OUTPUT *QUERY-IO*)` between them to ensure that the prompt is printed before trying to read anything.

Comment: Usually you would not call read-file recursively, but use a loop around the restart-case form.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Could you please give some background information why to avoid recursion here?

Comment: Without TCO you would have multiple invocations of READ-FILE on the stack in case of multiple invocations of the restart...