# What is SBCL's pathname wildcard conventions on macOS, Linux, FreeBSD?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Trying out Lisp today on my Mac, I found the following a bit disorienting:

```
$ sbcl
This is SBCL 1.4.14, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.

* (directory "*")
NIL

* (directory "*.*")
(#P"/private/tmp/sbcl/quicklisp.lisp" #P"/private/tmp/sbcl/test1.lisp"
 #P"/private/tmp/sbcl/test2.lisp")
```

On macOS, Linux, FreeBSD, probably most other UNIX-likes, `*` represents all files. I've only ever seen `*.*` used on DOS and Windows.

Per the [`directory` description](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dir.htm), wildcards are implementation dependent. So, then, what exactly is the convention used by SBCL on the above operating systems? How do I find this out? [SBCL's manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Pathnames) doesn't describe this. Could it be different even between the three OS' above?

Comment: Try `(describe #P"*")`, i.e. show how the pathname is parsed in terms of directory, name, etc.

Comment: Pathnames are a complicated issue which are inevitably somewhat implementation-dependent.  CL has a very elaborate pathname system which is more portable than it's often assumed to be, although it has the problem that pathnames have types (ie extensions) whereas on Unixoid systems they don't -- extensions are just a convention.  You probably want to have a look at what `parse-native-namestring` does: in particular what is `(pathname-type (parse-namestring "*"))` & how does it compare to `(pathname-type (parse-native-namestring "*"))`.

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832769/how-to-search-for-files-with-a-wildcard-in-common-lisp

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506750/portable-way-to-show-the-contents-of-the-current-directory

Comment: @tfb What are you expecting with these commands? Both ECL and SBCL return NIL for both of these.

Comment: I was hoping that the second would return something which told you what you needed for `directory` to work.  Obviously that's wrong.  I suspect (but an SBCL person would be better-placed to say) that the way you get *all* the files in a directory is by passing it a pathname representing the directory itself.

Comment: It doesn’t, actually. `(directory #P"/home/abc/")` gives me the directory name itself. A bit baffled. ECL does what I expect though.

Answer (score 1):

The [SBCL sources have this comment](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/filesys.lisp#L40):

> ```
> ;;; FIXME: the below shouldn't really be here, but in documentation
> ;;; (chapter 19 makes a lot of requirements for documenting
> ;;; implementation-dependent decisions), but anyway it's probably not
> ;;; what we currently do.
> ;;;
> ;;; Unix namestrings have the following format:
> ;;;
> ;;; namestring := [ directory ] [ file [ type [ version ]]]
> ;;; directory := [ "/" ] { file "/" }*
> ;;; file := [^/]*
> ;;; type := "." [^/.]*
> ;;; version := "." ([0-9]+ | "*")
> ;;;
> ;;; Note: this grammar is ambiguous. The string foo.bar.5 can be
> ;;; parsed as either just the file specified or as specifying the
> ;;; file, type, and version. Therefore, we use the following rules
> ;;; when confronted with an ambiguous file.type.version string:
> ;;;
> ;;; - If the first character is a dot, it's part of the file. It is not
> ;;; considered a dot in the following rules.
> ;;;
> ;;; - Otherwise, the last dot separates the file and the type.
> ;;;
> ;;; Wildcard characters:
> ;;;
> ;;; If the directory, file, type components contain any of the
> ;;; following characters, it is considered part of a wildcard pattern
> ;;; and has the following meaning.
> ;;;
> ;;; ? - matches any one character
> ;;; * - matches any zero or more characters.
> ;;; [abc] - matches any of a, b, or c.
> ;;; {str1,str2,...,strn} - matches any of str1, str2, ..., or strn.
> ;;;   (FIXME: no it doesn't)
> ;;;
> ;;; Any of these special characters can be preceded by an escape
> ;;; character to cause it to be treated as a regular character.
> ```

It says "but anyway it's probably not what we currently do", but I'm not sure if that is meant to mean that this comment may be inaccurate for current versions, or something else. I'm assuming at least the wildcard part is correct enough.

The important part here being that the directory, file and type components are all considered separately, so you must have a separate wildcard for both the filename and the extension (aka. the type component) with a dot to separate them.

The comment calls these "Unix namestrings", but I assume this applies to all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, and I think should work in most implementations (I have tried this on LW on MacOS, SBCL on Linux and Clojure on MacOS).

```
(defun directory-pathname (p)
  ;; Everything but the file part: this should be called
  ;; non-file-pathname or something
  (make-pathname :name nil :type nil :version nil
                 :defaults (pathname p)))

(defconstant +wild-file+
  ;; a completely wildcarded filename with no other components
  (make-pathname :name ':wild
                 :type ':wild
                 :version ':wild))

(defun wild-directory (d)
  ;; Take the directory parts of D and return a pathname which matches
  ;; all files in tat directory.
  ;;
  ;; Actually we could just use D for the defaults since it's only
  ;; used for defaults and that's less consy, but never mind
  (merge-pathnames +wild-file+ (directory-pathname d)))
```

Then, for instance `(directory (wild-directory "/tmp/"))` will return everything in the `/tmp/` directory, and `(directory (wild-directory (user-homedir-pathname)))` will return everything in your home directory.

However note that (this is clearly very implementation-dependent but it looks like all the implementations I use agree on this and I agree with their interpretation): `(directory (wild-directory "/tmp"))` will return *everything in `/`*, because `"/tmp"` as a pathname means 'the file called `tmp` in the directory called `/`'.  As I said I think this is a reasonable interpretation: pathnames which refer to directories end in `/`.

Also note that `+wild-file+` really is wild: it doesn't treat files whose names begin with `.` in any special way.  I think there is fairly obvious ambiguity about how filenames like `/foo/bar/.x` should be parsed, although all three implementations I've tried take what I think is the right interpretation: the name is `".x"` and the type is `nil` (`/foo/bar/.x.y` seems to parse with a type of `"y"` which I think is also reasonable).

In any case where you need to do any serious pathname manipulation the trick is to define a bunch of wrapper functions and constants which you then use, and behind which you can hide implementation-dependence (in this case the implementation-dependence is how to get all the files in a directory, everything else seems to be common between the implementations).

I suspect such an abstraction layer exists, but I don't know what it is unfortunately.

---

After writing this I tried CLISP, and it does something interestingly different: it looks like `directory` doesn't return subdirectory names, just filenames.  That's a perfectly reasonable implementation I think, but it would require some more abstraction.